# call revert exception; VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with panic code 17

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity

I'm trying to implement refund functionality in my crowdfunding smart contract.It should return donated amount if target has not reached after deadline has passed and if user has donated to campaign.

```
 function claimRefund(uint256 _id) public payable {
        Campaign storage campaign = campaigns[_id];

        require(campaign.deadline < block.timestamp, "The deadline has not passed yet.");
        require(campaign.amountCollected < campaign.target, "The campaign goal has been reached.");

        uint256 amount = donatedAmount[msg.sender];
        require(amount > 0, "No refund is available for this address.");

        donatedAmount[msg.sender] = 0;
        campaign.amountCollected -= amount;

        (bool sent, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: amount}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send the refund.");
    }
```

when I try to implement above function I  keep getting error call revert exception .

```
call revert exception; VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with panic code 17 [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="claimRefund(uint256)", data="0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011", errorArgs=[{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x11"}], errorName="Panic", errorSignature="Panic(uint256)", reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0).
```

I have tried this code in remix ide .The code is working fine in remix but when I try to test in goerli its giving me above error .I have deployed this contract in gorlei testnet using thirdweb. I don't have slightest idea what causing error .

This is my code for smart contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract CrowdFunding {
    struct Campaign {
        address owner;
        string title;
        string description;
        uint256 target;
        uint256 deadline;
        uint256 amountCollected;
         bool closed;
        string image;
        address[] donators;
        uint256[] donations;
      
    }
      mapping(address => uint256) public donatedAmount;

    mapping(uint256 => Campaign) public campaigns;

    uint256 public numberOfCampaigns = 0;

    function createCampaign(
        address _owner,
        string memory _title,
        string memory _description,
        uint256 _target,
        uint256 _deadline,
        string memory _image
    ) public returns (uint256) {
  
        Campaign storage campaign = campaigns[numberOfCampaigns];
        require(campaign.deadline < block.timestamp, "The deadline should be a date in the future.");
        campaign.owner = _owner;
        campaign.title = _title;
        campaign.description = _description;
        campaign.target = _target;
         campaign.deadline =   _deadline;
        campaign.amountCollected = 0;
        campaign.image = _image;

        numberOfCampaigns++;

        return numberOfCampaigns - 1;
    }

    function donateToCampaign(uint256 _id) public payable {
        Campaign storage campaign = campaigns[_id];
         require(!campaign.closed,"The campaign is disabled");
        require(campaign.deadline > block.timestamp, "The deadline has already passed.");

        campaign.donators.push(msg.sender);
        campaign.donations.push(msg.value);
        donatedAmount[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        campaign.amountCollected += msg.value;

        if (campaign.amountCollected >= campaign.target) {
           
            (bool sent,) = payable(campaign.owner).call{value: campaign.amountCollected}("");
            require(sent, "Transfer to campaign owner failed.");
                    campaign.closed = true;
        }
    }

    function claimRefund(uint256 _id) public payable {
        Campaign storage campaign = campaigns[_id];

        require(campaign.deadline < block.timestamp, "The deadline has not passed yet.");
        require(campaign.amountCollected < campaign.target, "The campaign goal has been reached.");

        uint256 amount = donatedAmount[msg.sender];
        require(amount > 0, "No refund is available for this address.");

        donatedAmount[msg.sender] = 0;
        campaign.amountCollected -= amount;

        (bool sent, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: amount}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send the refund.");
    }

    function getDonators(uint256 _id) public view returns (address[] memory, uint256[] memory) {
        Campaign storage campaign = campaigns[_id];
        return (campaign.donators, campaign.donations);
    }

    function getCampaigns() public view returns (Campaign[] memory) {
        Campaign[] memory allCampaigns = new Campaign[](numberOfCampaigns);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < numberOfCampaigns; i++) {
            Campaign storage item = campaigns[i];

            allCampaigns[i] = item;
        }

        return allCampaigns;
    }



}
```